# Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters issue

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7, elasticsearch-mapping

I am posting to my nearly created Elasticsearch service, but unable to post the mapping. I can not identify which part is unsupported. Any suggestions?

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "employees": {
            "properties": {
                "FirstName": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "LastName": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "Designation": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "Salary": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "DateOfJoining": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                },
                "Address": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "Gender": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "Age": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "MaritalStatus": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "Interests": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I consistently get this error returned.

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [employees : {properties={Designation={type=text}, Salary={type=integer}, MaritalStatus={type=text}, DateOfJoining={format=yyyy-MM-dd, type=date}, Address={type=text}, FirstName={type=text}, LastName={type=text}, Gender={type=text}, Age={type=integer}, Interests={type=text}}}]"
            }
```

Using Version 7.6.2

Comment: which ES version?

Answer (score 6):

**As you didn't specify your Elasticsearch version, which I also asked in my comment,**

I have multiple versions of Elasticsearch and as you are using `text`, I started with `Elasticsearch 7` as, you also specified `employees` in your mapping, which created suspect as this is normally defined in older versions, where types are defined.

Please see [removal of types official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/removal-of-types.html) for more info and not it would be completely removed in coming major version of 8.X

I was able to reproduce the issue with Elasticsearch 7.6 and got the same error:

```
 "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [employees : {properties={Designation={type=text}, Salary={type=integer}, MaritalStatus={type=text}, DateOfJoining={format=yyyy-MM-dd, type=date}, Address={type=text}, FirstName={type=text}, LastName={type=text}, Gender={type=text}, Age={type=integer}, Interests={type=text}}}]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [employees : {properties={Designation={type=text}, Salary={type=integer}, MaritalStatus={type=text}, DateOfJoining={format=yyyy-MM-dd, type=date}, Address={type=text}, FirstName={type=text}, LastName={type=text}, Gender={type=text}, Age={type=integer}, Interests={type=text}}}]",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [employees : {properties={Designation={type=text}, Salary={type=integer}, MaritalStatus={type=text}, DateOfJoining={format=yyyy-MM-dd, type=date}, Address={type=text}, FirstName={type=text}, LastName={type=text}, Gender={type=text}, Age={type=integer}, Interests={type=text}}}]"
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

### Solution

**Simply remove the `employee` from your `mapping` and use below mapping.**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": { --> note `employees` removed.
            "FirstName": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "LastName": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "Designation": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "Salary": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "DateOfJoining": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
            },
            "Address": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "Gender": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "Age": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "MaritalStatus": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "Interests": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Above create index successfully**

```
{
    "acknowledged": true,
    "shards_acknowledged": true,
    "index": "mustnot"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using version 7.x of Elasticsearch, which [doesn't support mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) anymore. You simply need to remove `employees`, like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "FirstName": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "LastName": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "Designation": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "Salary": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "DateOfJoining": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      },
      "Address": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "Gender": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "Age": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "MaritalStatus": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "Interests": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you beat me in this , I was asking for ES version and started repro the issue and you just posted answer within 3 mins of posting question, amazing ‍♂️, missed it by few seconds , hope one day I would beat you in this race 

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja rest assured, it's not a race, there's no final line ;-)

Comment: Ha ha, but its a game for sure :)