# How to fix the mapping structure for Elastic search ? I am trying to migrate from 5.6 to 7.10

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, mapping

Need help with fixing mapping of ES from 5.6 to 7.10

Below is a sample structure. Tried multiple things, but doesnt seem to work, need help.

```
  "_parent": {
    "type": "brand"
  },
  "properties": {
    "brand": {
      "type": "nested",
      "include_in_parent": true,
      "properties": {
        "encrypted_id": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "store": true
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "store": true,
          "fields": {
            "sort": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "sort_analyzer",
              "fielddata": true
            }
          },
          "analyzer": "stemmer_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
 }
}
```

Below is the error message I am getting

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [product : {properties={brand={include_in_parent=true, type=nested, properties={encrypted_id={store=true, type=keyword}, name={analyzer=stemmer_analyzer, store=true, type=text, fields={sort={fielddata=true, analyzer=sort_analyzer, type=text}}}}}}}] [company_profile : {properties={modified_ts={format=dateOptionalTime, store=true, ignore_malformed=true, type=date}, company_type={store=true, type=keyword}, country={store=true, type=keyword}, facebook_url={store=true, type=keyword}, account_type={store=true, type=keyword}, featured={include_in_parent=true, type=nested, properties={display_order={store=true, type=long}, event_encrypted_id={store=true, type=keyword}, is_featured={store=true, type=boolean}}}, created_dt={format=dateOptionalTime, store=true, ignore_malformed=true, type=date}, encrypted_id={store=true, type=keyword}, custom_fields={include_in_parent=true, type=nested, properties={buyer_50_fields={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}},
```

Updated:

```
PUT /test_0001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "brand": {
        "properties": {
          "encrypted_id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "sort": {
                "type": "keyword"  
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error:
Below is the error message I am getting

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [brand : {properties={encrypted_id={type=keyword}, name={type=text, fields={sort={type=keyword}}}}}]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [properties]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [brand : {properties={encrypted_id={type=keyword}, name={type=text, fields={sort={type=keyword}}}}}]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [brand : {properties={encrypted_id={type=keyword}, name={type=text, fields={sort={type=keyword}}}}}]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

The mapping code is of ES 5.6 and the latest one we are using is 7.10

Even after fixing getting the same error

```
Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [product : {properties={min_msrp={type=double}, is_immediate={type=boolean}, price_visibility_level={type=keyword}, is_published={type=boolean}, display_order={type=long}, description={type=text}, locale={type=keyword}, max_msrp={type=double}, product_images={type=nested, properties={encrypted_id={type=keyword}, name={type=text, fields={sort={type=text}}}}}, msrp_price={type=double}, premium={type=nested, properties={is_premium={type=boolean}, display_order={type=long}}}, company_profile={type=nested, properties={account_type={type=keyword}, encrypted_id={type=keyword}, name={type=text, fields={sort={type=text}}}}}, has_default_sku={type=text}, most_viewed_count={type=long}, price={type=double}, immediate_display_order={type=long}, visibility_level={type=keyword}, company={type=nested, properties={external_checkout_commerce={type=boolean}, allowed_buyer={type=text}, is_connection_requirement_turned_off={type=boolean}, encrypted_id={type=keyword}, subscription_type={type=keyword}, payment_ready={type=boolean}}}, currency={type=keyword}, tag={type=nested, properties={name={type=text, fields={sort={type=text}}}}}, sku={type=text}, stock={type=long}, trackInventory={type=long}, brand={type=nested, properties={encrypted_id={type=keyword}, name={type=text, fields={sort={type=text}}}}}, group={type=nested, properties={cancel_end={format=date_optional_time, type=date}, image={type=nested, properties={encrypted_id={type=keyword}}}, cancel_end_display={format=date_optional_time, type=date}, launch_start={format=date_optional_time, type=date}, encrypted_id={type=keyword}, is_published={type=boolean}, order_end={format=date_optional_time, type=date}, display_order={type=long}, description={type=text}, launch_end_display={format=date_optional_time, type=date}, is_public={type=boolean}, name={type=text, fields={sort={type=text}}}, launch_end={format=date_optional_time, type=date}, delivery_end={format=date_optional_time, type=date}, delivery_start={format=date_optional_time, type=date}, delivery_start_display={format=date_optional_time, type=date}, is_default_product={type=boolean}, order_end_display={format=date_optional_time, type=date}, is_featured={type=boolean}, launch_start_display={format=date_optional_time, type=date}, delivery_end_display={format=date_optional_time, type=date}}}, info={type=nested, properties={definition_id={type=keyword}, display_order={type=long}, id={type=keyword}, label={type=keyword}, type={type=keyword}, value={type=keyword, fields={date={type=date}, number={type=long}, bool={type=boolean}, decimal_number={type=double}, text={type=text}}}, required={type=boolean}}}, company_customfields={type=nested, properties={customfield_id={type=keyword}, customfield_name={type=text}, display_order={type=long}, customfield_value_id={type=keyword}, customfield_value={type=keyword}}}, has_buying_option={type=boolean}, images={type=nested, properties={encrypted_id={type=keyword}, display_order={type=long}, is_default={type=boolean}}}, created_dt={format=date_optional_time, type=date}, encrypted_id={type=keyword}, sku_is_immediate={type=long}, companyprofile_display_order={type=long}, max_price={type=double}, min_price={type=double}, name={type=text, fields={sort={type=text}}}, product_display_order={type=long}, category={type=nested, properties={encrypted_id={type=keyword}, name={type=text, fields={sort={type=text}}}}}, showtoexhibitors={type=keyword}, is_featured={type=boolean},
```

Comment: What's the error message? Probably something related to `_parent` which has been deprecated. Please add it to your question, it'd help, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the update. This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61081699/4604579

Comment: @Val, How can we have nested types here ?

Comment: @Val, Getting the same error even after fixing

Comment: @ManojK, Creating the `test_0001` index does not create an issue. What exactly are you doing to have the `Failed to parse mapping...` error? Could you show a sample document ? What is you procedure to migrate the data ?

Comment: The last error you're showing mentions `product` which is nowhere to be found in your JSON mapping. Can you provide the EXACT commands and payload you're using so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I am trying to use"type" as product when creating mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 5.6 to 7.10, [mapping types have been removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/removal-of-types.html) and it is not possible anymore to create several mapping types inside a 7.x index.

If you want to keep using your custom type name, you can do so by specifying `include_type_name=true` at index creation time. It will work, but you'll get a deprecation warning in your server logs.

Also, including a custom type name won't work once you upgrade from 7.10 to 8.x. So you can safely proceed that way for now, but you should remove your custom type name and use the unique and default type name, which is called `_doc`.